# Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 The column 'BID_Close' was specified multiple times for 't'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I already found a problem for this on StackOverflow link:-
[SQL Server 2008 Specified column was specified multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737767/sql-server-2008-specified-column-was-specified-multiple-times) but it doesn't help me much.

The below code throws an exception. How can I fix this?

```
--Calculating the average true range---------
WITH cteRange AS 
(
    SELECT 
        t.[Date],
        ROUND(t.[BID_High] - t.[BID_Low], 5) AS [H-L],
        ABS(ROUND(t.[BID_High] - t.[BID_Close], 5)) AS [H-Cp],
        ABS(ROUND(t.[BID_Low] - t.[BID_Close], 5)) AS [L-Cp]
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             *, 
             [BID_Close]  = LAG([BID_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])
         FROM 
             [STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS]) AS t 
), cteTrueRange AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM cteRange
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT MAX(v) AS v
        FROM (VALUES ([H-L]), ([H-Cp]), ([L-Cp])) AS value(v)
    ) AS sub([TR])
), cteTrueRange10 AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG([TR], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR1],
        LAG([TR], 2) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR2],
        LAG([TR], 3) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR3],
        LAG([TR], 4) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR4],
        LAG([TR], 5) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR5],
        LAG([TR], 6) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR6],
        LAG([TR], 7) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR7],
        LAG([TR], 8) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR8],
        LAG([TR], 9) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS [TR9]
    FROM cteTrueRange
)
SELECT 
    [Date], [H-L], [H-Cp], [L-Cp], [TR], [TRA]
FROM 
    cteTrueRange10
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN [TR9] IS NOT NULL THEN AVG(v) END AS v
        FROM (VALUES ([TR]), ([TR1]), ([TR2]), ([TR3]), ([TR4]), ([TR5]), ([TR6]), ([TR7]), ([TR8]), ([TR9])) AS value(v)
    ) AS sub([TRA]);
```

Error:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   The column 'BID_Close' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: Just define which column belongs to which CTE here- SELECT [Date], [H-L], [H-Cp], [L-Cp], [TR], [TRA].... like  cteRange.[H-L]...

Comment: @mkRabbani Sorry I can't understand what you say. I am getting an exception for with cteRange where I used t as an alias

Comment: You have - "SELECT *, [BID_Close]....". I guess its specified twice. One from "SELECT *" and another one you defined. You can try with a different name for [BID_Close] as [BID_Close_test] just for test purpose.

Comment: @mkRabbani so you are saying that I have to write     SELECT *, [BID_Close]  AS [BID_CLOSE-TEST] = LAG([BID_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])

Comment: SELECT *, [BID_CLOSE-TEST] = LAG([BID_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
(SELECT 
     *, 
     [BID_Close]  = LAG([BID_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])
 FROM 
     [STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS]) AS t
```

It would appear that the `STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS` table/view has a column called `BID_Close`, which gets selected by the `*` in your `SELECT` statement. On top of that, you also define a new column with an alias of `BID_Close` (defined by that `LAG(...)`) - so now your dataset being selected has **TWO** columns called `BID_Close` and that's causing the error.

You could fix this by:

- **NOT** selecting `*` but just those columns you **really** need (certainly omitting the `BID_Close` column):

  ```
  SELECT 
      (list of columns, except BID_Close),
      [BID_Close]  = LAG([BID_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])
  ```
- Defining a different column alias for that calculated column
   `[BID_Close_Last] = LAG([BID_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])`
  so that the column from your underlying table is `BID_Close`, and your newly calculated value is referred to as `BID_Close_Last`